# ClickOnce not installing on user's pc

Tags: winforms, deployment, clickonce, onedrive

I'm using ClickOnce to deploy a Winforms app. The app is for my client, and not general release, and they need to install it on tens of Surface tablets.

At the moment, the setup.exe file is on a shared onedrive, with the remaining files on a website.

When I install on my test tablet, it works fine. When the client does, they get an error with a long path pointing at c:\users\[accountname]\appdata\local\apps\2.0\etc and the message:

"Windows cannot access the specified device, path or file. You may not have appropriate permissions to access the item."

While the online documentation implies that non-admin users can install:

**Security permissions.** Windows Installer deployment requires administrative permissions and allows only limited user installation; ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the application.

I do not have the application signed, which may be the issue. if it is, what is the best signing option for what is effectively an internal application where we all trust and know each other (other documentation refers to a code-signing option as :

- Receive one from a group in your organization responsible for creating digital certificates

If that is the answer, how do I go about this (I am not the admin).

I expected the user to see the same results I got on my test tablet. That is, other than a warning from Defender SmartScreen preventing the unrecognised app from starting which appears on my tablet, and for which I can click 'more info' and then 'run anyway', I was not expecting any problem.